# merge to dataframe with column and value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dfs to match:

df1:

```
Index x  y
0     5  10
1     6  15 
2     7  8
```

df2:

```
Index a  b  c 
0     -  -  5
1     -  -  5
2     -  -  5
3     6  -  -
4     6  7  -
5     6  7  -
6     -  7  -
```

Is there a way to match these two dfs - the column `df1['x']` represents the values of `df2['a'],df2['b'],df2['c']`?

I have to merge df1 and `df2` to `df2` by transfer the y-value of df1 to df2 when `df1['x']` in one of the colums `df['a'], df['a'] or df['c']`.

Expected Output: `df2 =`

```
Index a  b  c  y_a  y_b  y_c  y_total
0     -  -  5  -    -    10   10
1     -  -  5  -    -    10   10
2     -  -  5  -    -    10   10 
3     6  -  -  15   -    -    15
4     6  7  -  15   8    -    23
5     6  7  -  15   8    -    23
6     -  7  -  -    8    -    8
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your first 2 dataframes have 5 columns in total but in your expected output there are 7.  It's also unclear how you're expecting missing values to be handled and whether you want to merge by index or some other criteria.

Comment: I edit the Question. I want to merge df1 and df2 to df2 by transfer the y-value of df1 to df2 when df1['x'] in one of the colums df['a'], df['a'] or df['c']. After that the colum df2['y_total'] should be no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `stack` to reshape then use `pd_to_numeric` to convert the dtype of stacked dataframe to numeric type, then `map` the values from `df1` and use `unstack` to reshape back creating new dataframe `y`, finally `join` the dataframe `df2` with `y`:

```
y = pd.to_numeric(df2.stack(), errors='coerce')\
      .map(df1.set_index('x')['y']).unstack().add_prefix('y_')
      
out = df2.join(y.assign(y_total=y.sum(1)))
```

Result:

```
print(out)

   a  b  c   y_a  y_b   y_c  y_total
0  -  -  5   NaN  NaN  10.0     10.0
1  -  -  5   NaN  NaN  10.0     10.0
2  -  -  5   NaN  NaN  10.0     10.0
3  6  -  -  15.0  NaN   NaN     15.0
4  6  7  -  15.0  8.0   NaN     23.0
5  6  7  -  15.0  8.0   NaN     23.0
6  -  7  -   NaN  8.0   NaN      8.0
```

Comment: Thats it! Thx!!

Comment: @Vini Happy coding!